# fgets and strtok in a double "for" loop

Tags: c, file, loops, token, fgets

I'm trying to extract the content of a file into a matrix but the file may look completely differently.

For exemple all these files should give the same result : a 3x3 matrix containing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

---

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

---

```
1  2  3 
4 5 6
7         8 9
```

---

```
1 2 3 4
5
6
7   8 
9
```

---

```
1 2 3
$something
$something else
4 5 6
$something else else
7 8 9
```

---

Hopefully I know the dimensions of the matrix beforehand as well as the "$" character that indicates that these lines are to be ignored in the current process.

My current algorithm using fscanf works great but It can't work with the "$something" lines.

I figured that I should use the fgets/strtok/sscanf method but there are some issues.

```
// File* file (already assigned)
char line[32]; //assuming 32 is enough
char* token;

fgets(line,32,file);
token = strtok(line," \t");

for (y=0; y<ySize; y++)
{
    for (x=0; x<xSize, x++)
    {
        if (token[0] == '$') //should use a str function
        {
            fgets(line,32,file);
            token = strtok(line," \t")
            x--;
        }
        else
        {
            if (we are at the end of the line)
            {
                fgets(line,32,file);
                token = strtok(line," \t")
            }
            sscanf(token,"%d",&matrix[x][y];
            token = strtok(NULL," \t");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'd like to have some help to write the "if (we are at the end of the line)" condition and some input on my method, is it flawless? Did I correctly thought of the process?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html). You can use the 2nd argument to setup a call chain that goes through a whole line.

Comment: Are comments only full lines, or would a line like `1 2 $ignore` be allowed?

Comment: 1 2 $ignore is not possible. But bascially I would just have to call 'token == $' each time (still got some research to do about token and all). 1 $ignore 2 is not possible either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getline` instead of `fgets` to make things easier. The latter is unreliable. The test condition that you are looking for is:

```
token == NULL;
```

Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/): "Once the terminating null character of str has been found in a call to strtok, all subsequent calls to this function with a null pointer as the first argument return a null pointer."

Comment: What do you consider "unreliable" about `fgets`?

Comment: For streams opened in text mode, fseek has limited use, because carriage return-linefeed translations can cause fseek to produce unexpected results. The only fseek operations guaranteed to work on streams opened in text mode are:

* Seeking with an offset of 0 relative to any of the origin values.
* Seeking from the beginning of the file with an offset value returned from a call to ftell.

Comment: You mean a while on x and y? What would be the difference? 

Ans isn't strtok(NULL," \t") required to go on the next element of the string?

Comment: Your original comment was about fgets, but your reply is about fseek and ftell. This shows nothing about fgets being unreliable.

Comment: I think that fgets has the same mechanics as fseek, am I wrong?

Comment: Also, the while loop would seem more of a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse without strtok() by using strspn() / strcspn(), and sscanf()s "%n" specifier. Also: there was a ',' in the original code where a ';' should have been.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define XSIZE 3
#define YSIZE 3

int matrix[XSIZE][YSIZE];

int main(void)
{
char line[200];
int pos,eat,xx,yy, rc;

xx = yy =0;
while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) ) {
    if (line[0] == '$') continue;
    for(pos=0; line[pos]; pos += eat) {
       pos += strspn(line+pos, " \t\n");
       rc =sscanf(line+pos, "%d%n", &matrix[xx][yy], &eat);
       if (rc < 1) break;
       if (++xx >= XSIZE ) {xx = 0; if(++yy >= YSIZE) goto done; }
       }   
     }
done:
        /* show it to the world ... */
for (yy = 0; yy < YSIZE; yy++) {
    for (xx = 0; xx < XSIZE; xx++) {
        fprintf (stdout, " %d", matrix[xx][yy] );
        }       
    fprintf (stdout, "\n" );
    }   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: that is more or less what I was thinking with the while loop, but I think it is easier to read with the for loops and performance should be about the same. Thumbs up though for this!

Comment: The original code used fgets() in three different places (which is ugly IMHO). In most cases, putting fgets() in the outer loop will yield the cleanest code. Performance is a non-issue, most of the time is spent inside sscanf(), and the number of calls to sscanf() is the same. Also: the original did not check fgets() or sscanf()'s return code.

Comment: yes, indeed, but you use a label, and that's something I wouldn't advise!

Comment: If you can rewrite the program without a goto, without extra complexity (such as repeated conditions, or even worse: indicator variables): be my guest!

Comment: hey mate, don't get defensive, goto is a valid c keyword, so there's nothing wrong to using it. I just stated my liking.